# Filling the wrong area after doubling

Tags: tikz-pgf, fill

After doubling around a path, and filling the comment `\fill` is filling the wrong area, how can I fill what's inside, please?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}    
\def\A{(2,1) to[out=80,in=0] (0,3) }

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round, line cap= round]
\begin{scope}
\draw[double, double distance=1cm] \A;
\fill[fill=black] \A;
\end{scope}
\draw \A;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are filling the curve `(2,1) to[out=80,in=0] (0,3)` implicitly closed by a straight line from end to start. I am  not sure why this surprises you --- what do you think it should have been?

Comment: Thank you @Rmano, I am not that good with these, and what I am looking for is to fill the doubled area (the potatoes shape) with lines. Could you help please?

Comment: If you just want it black, you could perhaps do `\draw[line width=1cm]  \A;`. With the pen you have, you will probably get what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Rmano [explained](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646761/filling-the-wrong-area-after-doubling#comment1611597_646761), you asked Ti*k*Z to fill an open curve defined by `(2,1) to[out=80,in=0] (0,3)`, therefore Ti*k*Z closed the curve by joining the endpoints with a straight line, then filled it.

In order to fill the “bean” in black, you can pass `double=black`: this sets the inner color to `black` when using the `double distance` key (cf. the [Ti*k*Z & PFG manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) §15.3.4, *Graphic Parameters: Double Lines and Bordered Lines*).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round]
\draw[double=black, double distance=1cm] (2,1) to[out=80,in=0] (0,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But as @mickep [noted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646761/filling-the-wrong-area-after-doubling/646778#comment1611603_646761), a similar effect (identical?) can be obtained using a simple `\draw` with a large pen:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round]
\draw[line width=1cm] (2,1) to[out=80,in=0] (0,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: I removed the `line join=round` in both cases, as it doesn't seem to change anything here.

Comment: Thank you @frougon Is there a way to fill it with something else ( lines or crosshatch dots for example)rather than a colour?

Comment: I don't think it can be done this way because we only use stroke operations here, no filling (the “middle” of `double` is a stroke executed after a wider one which produces the “borders”). In order to fill the area with a pattern, I believe we would first need to define a closed path around our bean.

Comment: thank you. Is there a way to define such a path? which is in fact a closed curve around the path that's in the middle?

Comment: Exactly the same, probably... for someone who knows precisely how the above strokes are performed in geometric terms. Practically, I'd suggest to build an approximation using completely different techniques (`to` operations, `arc` operations, [hobby](https://ctan.org/pkg/hobby)...). But that is another question. :-)